# Splitting text at a determined character using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes a .txt file with a messy text, read it and every time it comes across a full stop (.) it should create a new line, essentially breaking every paragraph into several. However I'm struggling to find something that will actually look for the specified character within the text.

I was thinking about having the program read the text character by character, then writing them to a different file and having it add a "\n" whenever it ran across a ".", but I'm having troubles implementing it along the lines of:

```
    with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
     while True:
      char = f.read(1)
      if not char:
      break
     else:
      if char==("."):
       f.write(char + "\n")
      else:
       f.write(char)
    break
```

I'm guessing this particular piece of code is a bloody mess, but I've been struggling with this problem for some time and at this point I'm trying pretty much anything I can think of.

Comment: Why not read the whole thing and do a `replace('.','.\n')`?

Comment: Should the full stop be removed or should the line break be inserted after the full stop?

Comment: @AntonvBR I've actually gone and done that since posting this question, and it really is a lot simpler, now all i need to do is input exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try below:

```
 with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    data=f.read().replace('.', '.\n')
```

Comment: Yeah, directly replacing the characters is a lot simpler. Thanks.